# Using Global.var in NodeJS to temporarily store redirect URL to use after OAuth callback

Tags: node.js, oauth, global

I have a nodejs app (http://app.winetracker.co) and I'm integrating OAuth logins. I think I can use a global.redirectURL var to temporarily store the redirect URL for use after the OAuth callback.

```
// url param passed to route /auth/twitter?redirectUrl=/path/to/location

app.get('/auth/twitter', function(req, res) {
    var redirectUrl = req.param('redirectUrl');
    global.redirectUrl = req.param('redirectUrl');
    passport.authenticate('twitter', {})(req, res);
});
app.route('/auth/twitter/callback').get(users.oauthCallback('twitter'));
```

If I have 2 users logging into my app via OAuth at the same time, will the global.redirectURL values get overwritten by each user's redirect var value?

Essentially, are global values unique to each user or does *everyone* share the same global.redirectUrl var value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have 2 users logging into my app via OAuth at the same time, will
>   the global.redirectURL values get overwritten by each user's redirect
>   var value?

Yes, they will get overwritten and doing it this way is a serious problem.

> Essentially, are global values unique to each user or does everyone
>   share the same global.redirectUrl var value?

Global values are shared with your entire server so storing anything there is visible by ALL requests by all users that might be processing.  You should pretty much never store this kind of temporary information in a global.  If the auth code is async (which I assume it is), then you can easily have multiple requests trouncing/conflicting with that global.  This is a bug ridden thing to do.  You must change to a different way of solving the issue.

The usual solutions to this type of issue that do not have the vulnerability of a global include the following:

1. Use a session manager and place the data into the session for this particular browser so it can be retrieved from there during the redirect.
2. Put the information as a query parameter on the redirect URL so when the browser comes back with the redirect URL, you can parse it out of the query string then.
3. Coin a unique ID for this request, set it as a cookie and store the temporary data in a map using the ID as the key.  Then, when the redirect comes back, you can use the cookie to get the ID and then lookup the value in the map.  This is essentially a session, but it's special purpose just for this purpose.  To be thorough, you also have to make sure your map doens't leak and build up over time so you have to probably store a timestamp and regular clean up the map by removing old values.

Comment: Thanks! That totally clears things up for me.  Cheers. :)

Comment: So is it as simple as storing it in req.session?
    
    req.session.redirectUrl

Comment: @tonejac - If you already have a session established, then whatever mechanism your session uses for saving new info to it is all it takes.  I wasn't sure the session that passport uses was necessarily established yet for a first time user who has not yet authenticated.